# What were the rules of fighting in "Chakravyuha"?

Tags: mahabharata

- Is their any explanation on how chakravyuha was created?
- What were the rules of fighting in chakravyuha?
- What exactly it was and purpose?
- Were there any similar types of war structures that existed?

Comment: Regarding the last part of the question, I remember hearing about a battle formation shaped like a Swastika.

Comment: Please refer this http://www.quora.com/What-was-the-right-strategy-for-Abhimanyu-to-defeat-the-Padmavyuha-formation-from-the-Mahabharata/answer/Navin-Pai-1?srid=tlB0&share=1